# How do I change the project directory in App Engine Launcher?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a project (a version of which has already been deployed) in the App Engine Launcher, and I would like to change the project directory, as I have since moved the project files to a new directory. But, when I click to edit the project, the option to browse to a different directory is disabled.

I am using App Engine SDK 1.5.4 on Windows XP. Thanks in advance for your help.

It looks like this is a known issue ([here](http://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/issues/detail?id=12)), but the poster says s/he is running Ubuntu, not Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always delete (Ctrl+Del) and add the application again its not a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't sure if that would create a new project in App Engine. I can now confirm that, assuming the project name is the same, it does not create a new project.